# Error when rendering HTML in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying out a simple one page render and I'm obviously doing it wrong:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('home.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
```

I want to load a page with CSS/images and wanted to know where to store the CSS/images/scripts/HTML and how to load it. I have yet to find many example express apps.

Answer (score 4):

When using `res.render`, you are rendering a defined view. The documentation state:

> Render a view with a callback responding with the rendered string.
>   When an error occurs next(err) is invoked internally.

For specific HTML, you either have to load the file with `fs.readFile`, or have Express use a rendering engine, such as Jade or EJS. For example, this code sample would apply the EJS render engine to all files with the extension `.html`.

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Then you can render a file like this. This is an example of passing variables to the HTML file, because that's what embedded JavaScript is used for.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('/file', {
    pass: 'arguments',
    to: 'the file here'
  });
});
```

That is more convenient than having to read the file on each load like so:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('/index.html', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

Although this is aside from your question, this is how passing variables to EJS works. It even works with `if` statements and `loops`, since it accepts all JavaScript. Putting `console.log` in the file would log each time the file was rendered.

```
<span><%= pass %></span>
<!-- after rendering -->
<span>arguments</span>
```

If you need to serve other resources, such as CSS, JavaScript, or other html files, you could use Express' directory function.

```
app.use(express.static('/'));
```

Then you wouldn't need to render your HTML at all. It would be statically served.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to load a html with css/images and wanted to know what is the layout of where to store the css/img/js and the html and load it? I am yet to find many example express js apps.

Assuming that you have installed express, within your express project you will find **public** folder. within public folder you will find three folder - **images**, **javascripts**, and **stylesheets** . As the names suggest place your css/img/js in their respective folders.

Comment: You need to set up `express.static` or its equivalent for this to actually work, as discussed in the accepted answer from a few months before.

Answer (score 1):

You place **static HTML** files  not using any templates in the in the express project **public** folder and invoke it using:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/home.html');
});
```